# How to add two .xib files into two different sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7, xib

I am working on a UITableView. I need to have two different sections and each section should have a .xib file. One xib works fine but I couldn't manage to make both work. The point that confuses me is, I cannot figure out how to add second xib's controller in the code. I appreciate if you can tell me the logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy

you can register your nib files in a method :

```
-(void)registerNibs
{
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellType1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellType1"];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellType2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellType2"];
}
```

and you in `CellForRow`

```
if (indexpath.section == 0)
    cell = (CellType1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellType1"];
else
    cell = (CellType2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellType2"];
```